# Prevent running slice on zero sized source slice files

Tags: azure-data-factory

My pipelines have source dataset of type AzureBLOB.

It's hourly dataset, so the pipelines keep pulling hourly slices. But the problem is that many of the source slice files are of **zero size**. But the pipelines proceed with that and succeed. I don't want that.

At the same time I don't want to hardcode any 'minimum' size policy in the pipeline 
(I know there is some such setting we can provide for pipeline ).

> I just want to say "Pipeline should process **nonzero** sized files only, no >matter what size. How do we ensure this? Basically the slice should be retrying >and eventually fail if the slice file is zero sized.

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom C# activity to check whether you have active data in Azure Blob and based on the outcome you can continue your pipeline

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/data-factory-use-custom-activities/